# Unable to show multiple whole pie charts using GGPlot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a dataset for Game Publishers which is clean and I'm able to plot multiple pie charts using the dataset but most of them are coming out as partial pie charts as shown in the image below

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxAO6.png)

The dataset has just 3 columns: Publisher, Geography, Sales.

| Publisher | Geography | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | UK | 1.1 |
| ABC | Other | 3 |
| DEF | UK | 1.3 |
| DEF | Other | 2.9 |

My code

```r
Top$Publisher <- as.factor(Top$Publisher)
Top$Geography <- as.factor(Top$Geography)

ggplot(Top, aes(x="", y = Sales, group = Geography, colour = Geography, fill = Geography)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  facet_grid(.~Publisher)
```

Not sure where the problem lies.

Any Pointers would be helpful.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just a general note on data visualization that a pie chart is probably the worst option you could choose. E.g. a bar chart seems to me more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `position = position_fill()`:

```r
ggplot(Top, aes(x="", y = Sales, group = Geography, colour = Geography, fill = Geography)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", position = position_fill()) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  facet_grid(.~Publisher)
```

[image]